# Finding most and least frequent rows of a text file in python

Tags: python, pandas, counter, mode

I have a text file with only one column containing text content. I want to find out the top 3 most frequent items and the 3 least frequent items. I have tried some of the solutions in other posts, but I am not able to get what I want. I tried finding the mode as shown below, but it just outputs all the rows. I also tried using the counter and the most common functions, but they do the same thing i.e. print all the rows in the file. Any help is appreciated.

```
# My Code

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.txt')

print(df.mode())
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share some data. Also, please read *[mcve]*.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Python's built-in [counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
from collections import Counter

# Read file directly into a Counter
with open('file') as f:
    cnts = Counter(l.strip() for l in f)

# Display 3 most common lines
cnts.most_common(3)

# Display 3 least common lines
cnts.most_common()[-3:]
```

Comment: @tdelaney Great suggestion! I've incorporated it into my answer